# How do I send my response in a API Route in next js when my data is in a .then promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, next.js, es6-promise

I am using next js with axios, and I have a .then promise inside a .then. I want to respond to the api request with the data I grabbed but if I put the res in the .then it is unreachable, but I don't know how to get the data out of the .then. Normally with async await I return the value and create a variable to the function but this does not seem to work with .then.

here is my code

```
let data;

  axios
    .post(
      "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
      serialize({
        grant_type: "client_credentials",
      }),
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Basic " + auth,
        },
      }
    )
    .then((res) => {
      axios
        .get(
          `https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=${name}&type=episode&market=US`,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${res.data.access_token}`,
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
          }
        )
        .then(function (response) {
          // handle success
          console.log(response.data.episodes);
          data = response.data.episodes;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          // handle error
          console.log(error);
        })
        .then(function () {
          // always executed
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

  res.status(200).json({ data: data });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following fixed it

```
const data = axios
    .post(
      "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
      serialize({
        grant_type: "client_credentials",
      }),
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Basic " + auth,
        },
      }
    )
    .then((res) => {
      const test = axios
        .get(
          `https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=${name}&type=episode&market=US`,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${res.data.access_token}`,
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
          }
        )
        .then(function (response) {
          // handle success
          // console.log(response.data.episodes);
          return response.data.episodes;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          // handle error
          console.log(error);
        });

      return test;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

  const boy = async () => {
    console.log("data", await data);
    res.status(200).json({ data: await data });
  };
  boy();
```

Comment: even simpler  `.then((res) => axios.get(....).then(....).catch(....))` - in other words, arrow function without `{}` has an implied `return`